# jquery get data attribute of input field on change

Tags: jquery, input-field

I am trying to  get the data attribute of this radio box:

```
<div id="corrieriContainer">
    <label><input checked="checked" type="radio" name="spedizione" data-courier="DHL" value="8.56">&euro; 8.56</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="spedizione" data-courier="FEDEX" value="6.23">&euro; 6.23</label>
</div>
```

with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#corrieriContainer").on('change','input[type=radio][name=spedizione]',function(){
var valore = $(this).prop('checked',true).val();
var corriere = $(this).prop('checked',true).data('courier');
    alert(corriere);
});
```

I always get "undefined" value. Why? I can correctly get $(this).prop('checked',true).val();, but not the data-attribute.

Can you help me understand?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need `.prop('checked',true)`, this is used to assign a value to a radio button or checkbox programmatically.

Since users are clicking it manually to change the value, no need for it.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#corrieriContainer").on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=spedizione]', function() {
    var valore = $(this).val();
    var corriere = $(this).data('courier');

    alert(corriere);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="corrieriContainer">
  <label><input checked="checked" type="radio" name="spedizione" data-courier="DHL" value="8.56">&euro; 8.56</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="spedizione" data-courier="FEDEX" value="6.23">&euro; 6.23</label>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works fine on the fiddle, but it doesn't in my page

Comment: Then, there might be something else wrong with the page. Any errors in the console?

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Are you still getting `undefined`?

Comment: yes, i still get "undefined" and that's weird, because I have pasted your code in mine, then I have pasted in a jsfiddle using the same version of jquery of the project, but the jsfiddle works, your code in mine, doesn't